# What does the 'Stack Exchange' entry in the 'My Logins' section of my account represent?

Tags: support, my-logins

I am a novice user of the Stack Exchange platform. I was recently reviewing the details of my accounts. Within the 'Settings' tab is a 'My Logins' section, i.e. Account > Settings > ACCESS > Your Logins. Interestingly, the 'Your Logins' text only button opens the 'My Logins' section (I expected it to open a 'Your Logins' section). In the 'My Logins' section, I have three entries. Two of the entries are email addresses I use to login to Stack Exchange. The third entry is 'Stack Exchange'. I've noticed that the last used date of the 'Stack Exchange' entry is always the same as that of one of my email addresses. The email addresses in the list make sense, but not the Stack Exchange entry. What does the 'Stack Exchange' entry represent?

[image]

Comment: It is a display bug that occasionally crops up after account merges or credential mismatches, but I don't myself understand why it does that. It's not a separate credential.

Comment: Can the 'Stack Exchange' entry be removed without causing any other issues?

Comment: My experience is that it would remove the actual credential tied to it as well, which you'd then have to re-add.

Comment: @animuson: Okay, that makes sense. I noticed that the last used date of the 'Stack Exchange' entry is always the same as the last used date of one of my login email addresses. That must be the credential it is tied to. It just so happens that I want to remove that credential anyway. Would it be wise to assume that deleting that credential will also remove the 'Stack Exchange' entry? Thanks.